# I cannot run my C++ app without running visual studio community 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I built my program and deleted visual studio(cause I didn't want it anymore) I cannot run my application.

The app first asks for two DLL files ( vcruntime140d.dll and ucrtbased.dll). I downloaded it then I got an error that the application could not start correctly (0xc000007b).

I reinstalled Visual Studio again and rebuilt it with a full database. Then delete the visual studio and tried to run the application again and I get the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately you complied a debug build of the program and it NEEDs the debug libraries. The Debug libraries are gone along with the IDE and its built-in debugger, and the runtime libraries that are easily downloaded and installed with a MSVC runtime installer are not the right libraries. You'll need to recompile the code (as a release build with MSVC or another toolchain) or do something too stupid to bring up even in a Stack Overflow comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if Microsoft still offers a third option: There used to be a build tools-only version for download that would contain the debug DLLs. The best option is still likely reinstall MSVC and perform a release build.

Comment: You can change the compiler to ```clang``` which is supported by every other c++ ide. Another solution is change Debug to Release Build.